# MYSQL Insert values with ID between set range (or next available ID)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

Let me explain the data structure I have.

This specific table will be used to organize a category/subcategory tree for a website.

[image: click here for table image]
As you can see, the main Categories (the ones without any parent) will be assigned IDs of 1 to 99.

Meanwhile, subcategories will be assigned an ID that starts with the parent's ID. For example, all subcategories that belong to category 1 will have an ID from 101 to 199; All subcategories that belong to category 2 will have an ID from 201 to 299, and so on.

**Here's the question:** Can I tell MYSQL to "INSERT value1, value2, value3" on the next available "slot" BETWEEN IDs 101 and 199?

As in, if there exists rows inserted with IDs 102,102,103,104 (like in the image above). MYSQL would automatically insert the next row with ID 105 if I say "INSERT BETWEEN 101 and 199".

If it isn't possible with MYSQL or a MYSQL procedure, can it be done with a function in PHP instead? (Retrieve all the values, do some math, then insert the data).

This specific rule won't break the website if it's not followed (As the table structure uses a parent_id as well) But exists for the sole purpose of making the database human readable and making people reading or organizing the data less confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get the biggest id bettwen 100 an 199 and count one up for every column to enter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a starter: I would not recommend doing that. A surrogate primary key should not have a particular functional meaning by itself; it is just there to uniquely identify a record, and potentially to serve as a reference for foreign keys. Let me also pinpoint that your system does not scale well, since it cannot support more than 9 root categories (or more than 99 subcategories for a given category, and so on).

That said: what you ask for is technically feasible - but it requires an addition scan on the table for each and every `insert`:

```
insert into mytable (category_id, parent_id, category_name, category_description)
select coalesce(max(category_id), 100) + 1, 1, 'Cat 1 Sub N', 'Cat1 Sub N'
from mytable
where category_id >= 101 and category_id < 200
having max(category_id) is null or max(category_id) < 199
```

The technique consists in using the `insert ... select ...` syntax, with an aggregate query that gets the high water mark of the given range. If the range is empty, we assign a default value that corresponds to the beginning of the range. If the range is full, the `insert` is not peformed.

Comment: Like i mentioned, the IDs being structured that way isn't a functional decision, it's because the people organizing the database wanted that element of "human readability". If you went past 9 categories your subcategories would then start at ID 1001 for Category 10.